# Bundle IdentityUser to ticket

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

This is a homework assignment. Where I have to make a website with MVC 2.2 and Make it possible to make a ticket with some basic info and link IdentityUser to the ticket.

**The Class:**

```
public class Ticket
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Klant { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Applicatie { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Onderwerp { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Omschrijving { get; set; }
    public DateTime Datum { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
}
```

**The Controller:**

```
public class TicketsController : Controller
{
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;

    UserManager<IdentityUser> _userManager;
    public TicketsController(UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager)
    {
        _userManager = userManager;
    }

    public TicketsController(ApplicationDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    // GET: Tickets
    public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
    {
        return View(await _context.Ticket.ToListAsync());
    }
```

**This is added to the controller at the moment.**

```
UserManager<IdentityUser> _userManager;
    public TicketsController(UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager)
    {
        _userManager = userManager;
    }
```

So I was asking myself how to do this and I would really appreciate it if someone knows what to do and can explain it well.

Thanks in advance.
If you need more info just ask.

Comment: What is the relationship between Ticket and IdentityUser? Will the IdentityUser have many tickets?

Comment: @TaoZhou yes you can have many tickets or just one depends on how many you make.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working scenario for creating one ticket with one IdentityUser.

1. `Ticket`

   ```
   public class Ticket
   {
       public int ID { get; set; }
       [Required]
       public string Klant { get; set; }
       [Required]
       public string Applicatie { get; set; }
       [Required]
       public string Onderwerp { get; set; }
       [Required]
       public string Omschrijving { get; set; }
       public DateTime Datum { get; set; }
       public string Status { get; set; }
       public string IdentityUserId { get; set; }
       public virtual IdentityUser IdentityUser { get; set; }
   }
   ```
2. `ApplicationDbContext`

   ```
   public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext
   {
       public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
           : base(options)
       {
       }
       public DbSet<Ticket> Tickets { get; set; }

       protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
       {
           base.OnModelCreating(builder);
           builder.Entity<Ticket>().HasOne(t => t.IdentityUser).WithMany();
       }
   }
   ```
3. `TicketsController`

   ```
   public class TicketsController : Controller
   {
       private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;
       private readonly UserManager<IdentityUser> _userManager;

       public TicketsController(ApplicationDbContext context
           , UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager)
       {
           _context = context;
           _userManager = userManager;
       }

       // GET: Tickets
       public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
       {
           var applicationDbContext = _context.Tickets.Include(t => t.IdentityUser);
           return View(await applicationDbContext.ToListAsync());
       }

       // GET: Tickets/Details/5
       public async Task<IActionResult> Details(int? id)
       {
           if (id == null)
           {
               return NotFound();
           }

           var ticket = await _context.Tickets
               .Include(t => t.IdentityUser)
               .FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.ID == id);
           if (ticket == null)
           {
               return NotFound();
           }

           return View(ticket);
       }

       // GET: Tickets/Create
       public IActionResult Create()
       {
           ViewData["IdentityUserId"] = new SelectList(_context.Users, "Id", "Id");
           return View();
       }

       // POST: Tickets/Create
       // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
       // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
       [HttpPost]
       [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
       public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("ID,Klant,Applicatie,Onderwerp,Omschrijving,Datum,Status,IdentityUserId")] Ticket ticket)
       {
           if (ModelState.IsValid)
           {
               _context.Add(ticket);
               await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
               return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
           }
           ViewData["IdentityUserId"] = new SelectList(_context.Users, "Id", "Id", ticket.IdentityUserId);
           return View(ticket);
       }

       // GET: Tickets/Edit/5
       public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int? id)
       {
           if (id == null)
           {
               return NotFound();
           }

           var ticket = await _context.Tickets.FindAsync(id);
           if (ticket == null)
           {
               return NotFound();
           }
           ViewData["IdentityUserId"] = new SelectList(_context.Users, "Id", "Id", ticket.IdentityUserId);
           return View(ticket);
       }

       // POST: Tickets/Edit/5
       // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
       // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
       [HttpPost]
       [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
       public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int id, [Bind("ID,Klant,Applicatie,Onderwerp,Omschrijving,Datum,Status,IdentityUserId")] Ticket ticket)
       {
           if (id != ticket.ID)
           {
               return NotFound();
           }

           if (ModelState.IsValid)
           {
               try
               {
                   _context.Update(ticket);
                   await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
               }
               catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
               {
                   if (!TicketExists(ticket.ID))
                   {
                       return NotFound();
                   }
                   else
                   {
                       throw;
                   }
               }
               return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
           }
           ViewData["IdentityUserId"] = new SelectList(_context.Users, "Id", "Id", ticket.IdentityUserId);
           return View(ticket);
       }

       // GET: Tickets/Delete/5
       public async Task<IActionResult> Delete(int? id)
       {
           if (id == null)
           {
               return NotFound();
           }

           var ticket = await _context.Tickets
               .Include(t => t.IdentityUser)
               .FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.ID == id);
           if (ticket == null)
           {
               return NotFound();
           }

           return View(ticket);
       }

       // POST: Tickets/Delete/5
       [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
       [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
       public async Task<IActionResult> DeleteConfirmed(int id)
       {
           var ticket = await _context.Tickets.FindAsync(id);
           _context.Tickets.Remove(ticket);
           await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
           return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
       }

       private bool TicketExists(int id)
       {
           return _context.Tickets.Any(e => e.ID == id);
       }
   }
   ```
4. `Create.cshtml`

   ```
   @model CoreIdentity2.Models.Ticket

   @{
       ViewData["Title"] = "Create";
   }

   <h1>Create</h1>

   <h4>Ticket</h4>
   <hr />
   <div class="row">
       <div class="col-md-4">
           <form asp-action="Create">
               <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
               <div class="form-group">
                   <label asp-for="Klant" class="control-label"></label>
                   <input asp-for="Klant" class="form-control" />
                   <span asp-validation-for="Klant" class="text-danger"></span>
               </div>
               <div class="form-group">
                   <label asp-for="Applicatie" class="control-label"></label>
                   <input asp-for="Applicatie" class="form-control" />
                   <span asp-validation-for="Applicatie" class="text-danger"></span>
               </div>
               <div class="form-group">
                   <label asp-for="Onderwerp" class="control-label"></label>
                   <input asp-for="Onderwerp" class="form-control" />
                   <span asp-validation-for="Onderwerp" class="text-danger"></span>
               </div>
               <div class="form-group">
                   <label asp-for="Omschrijving" class="control-label"></label>
                   <input asp-for="Omschrijving" class="form-control" />
                   <span asp-validation-for="Omschrijving" class="text-danger"></span>
               </div>
               <div class="form-group">
                   <label asp-for="Datum" class="control-label"></label>
                   <input asp-for="Datum" class="form-control" />
                   <span asp-validation-for="Datum" class="text-danger"></span>
               </div>
               <div class="form-group">
                   <label asp-for="Status" class="control-label"></label>
                   <input asp-for="Status" class="form-control" />
                   <span asp-validation-for="Status" class="text-danger"></span>
               </div>
               <div class="form-group">
                   <label asp-for="IdentityUserId" class="control-label"></label>
                   <select asp-for="IdentityUserId" class ="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.IdentityUserId"></select>
               </div>
               <div class="form-group">
                   <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
               </div>
           </form>
       </div>
   </div>

   <div>
       <a asp-action="Index">Back to List</a>
   </div>

   @section Scripts {
       @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
   }
   ```

Comment: is it also posible to just get the email addres in the "Klant" instant of the code for that identity under the form and how can I do Datetime.now in the "datum" so it will always take the date from the creation.

Comment: @RobinGroot Change `ViewData["IdentityUserId"] = new SelectList(_context.Users, "Id", "Id");` to return user email.